# How to work amountIn and amountOut in swapExactTokensForTokens of method smart contract?

Tags: tokens, bsc, pancakeswap

I don't understand, smb explain me how to work amountIn and amountOut?

For example:

I have 10bnb, I want to another token for 1 bnb, it means amountIn = 1bnb I understand it.
But, I can't understand amountOut, It means, amountOut = price of other token or it 1bnb/price token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the uniswap documentation https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapexacttokensfortokens, PancakeSwap uses Uniswap v2 contract so the same documentation applies.

Given an input to calculate the expected output you could call [`getAmountsOut`](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#getamountsout).